# How to change the Geometry of bmp image

Tags: linux, bmp

I am unable to change the geomentry of a bmp image. 
I am using Imagemagick libraray in ubuntu.
I have a image with geometry 268*78 i want to convert it to 384*78. I am using the command  `convert out.bmp -monochrome -resize 384x78 out3.bmp`. The command doesn't throw any error but the out3.bmp geometry doesnt change. can anyone tell me a way to change that.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you on and are you using `imagemagick` for this?

Comment: I am using  Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Comment: I've tried with a jpg file, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From the imagemagick website:

> widthxheight Maximum values of height and width given, aspect ratio
>   preserved.

Try:

> widthxheight! Width and height emphatically given, original aspect
>   ratio ignored.

```
convert out.bmp -resize 384x78! -monochrome out3.bmp
```

Comment: will try tomorrow and let you know the result and thanks for the explanation

Comment: It is stretching the image. instead it should be like in the below image.This is what how I want https://s31.postimg.org/5afrr9nq3/out3.jpg. If I followthe command it is showing like https://s31.postimg.org/hvoijod1n/out4.jpg

Comment: You need to ask the correct question to get the correct answer. I would suggest next time posting an image of what you want and an image of the expected result.

Comment: ok I will do that. Problem is this command  convert -units PixelsPerInch out.png -density 384 out5.png didn't worked for all the image formats